# Calling Python script with Selenium Webdriver from PC on a server

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a Python script that uses Selenium Webdriver. I want to run this on a server remotely.
When running my script directly on the server through command window, everything works fine.
But when I'm trying to trigger this remotely through a program on my local PC to the server, it doesn't work. It seems to stop at `driver = webdriver.Chrome(webdriverlink)`. It doesn't fail, it just won't continue. So it seems like it doesn't actually opens a browser. 
Isn't this possible when you're not logged in on the server and not running it directly from there?

I've saved my script in a py-file, and is triggering it in both ways throuh the command line `python <myFileName>.py`

Comment: Have you installed the relevant driver on the remote machine?

Comment: Yes, I have. Or else I wouldn't have managed to run it directly on the server..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution from another forum after a lot of searching. So for all of you struggling with the same problem, this worked for me:

I've added the following code:
`options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()`
`options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])`

and changed from: `driver = webdriver.Chrome(webdriverlink)` 
to `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=webdriverlink,options=options)`